# Getting error about the .email tempate when using volt-mailer

Tags: ruby, volt, voltrb

So I have what appears to be a completely valid .email view, all written based on the docs.

```
<:Subject>
  Splatoon/Notify

<:Html>
  <h1>Welcome {{ name }}</h1>

  <p>Thanks for using Splatoon/Notify. We hope you enjoy the service.</p>

<:Text>
Welcome {{ name }}! Thanks for using Splatoon/Notify. We hope you enjoy the service.
```

It's being called by this task, inside mailer_tasks.rb

```
def onboard_user(email)
  Mailer.deliver('app/main/views/mailers/onboard.email', {to: email, :via => :smtp})
end
```

and yet it throws this error

```
Unable to find view at `app/main/views/mailers/onboard.email/subject`
```

Why would it be looking for a /subject path? I can't find any question on StackOverflow about the mailer gem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the `app` at the beginning of the path.  Also, you don't need the .email at the end.  Try that and let me know if it works.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Changed the path to `/main/views/mailers/onboard`.
Adding the `.email` doesn't work either.

Comment: Try this: ```main/mailers/onboard```

Comment: This video explains some of how view lookup works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1yNMP3XR6jU